# JAXB: xsd + xjb to POJO without annotations

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I got stuck trying to convert a XSD + XJB file to a POJO that has no JAXB annotations inside its code.

Project structure:

- pom.xml
- src/main/resources/schema.xsd

The file schema.xsd can be found [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/issues/src/main/resources/schema.xsd) as an example.

I am using Maven and the plugin **[jaxb2-basics-annotate](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin)**

Here is my maven file (pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>xsd-to-pojo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XSD to Pojo</name>
    <properties>
        <plugin.version>1.1.0</plugin.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.3.1</jaxb.version>
        <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.14.0</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                        <arg>-XremoveAnnotation</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                            <version>${plugin.version}</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the command **mvn** on command line, I get the following Java file, generated in the /target directory:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "gh16Type", propOrder = {
    "x"
})
public class Gh16Type {

    protected Object x;

    public Object getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Object value) {
        this.x = value;
    }

    public boolean isSetX() {
        return (this.x!= null);
    }
}
```

@XmlAccessorType and @XmlType should be removed. But they are still there.

Thanks for any help !

If you get it to work, try to put the file [binding.xjb](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/issues/src/main/resources/binding.xjb) under src/main/resources/ and try again.

Answer (score 0):

To [demonstrate (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-sample-resourced-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) a solution, [this](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/README.md) Maven project uses the [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) to generate **JAXB** classes with annotations; then, it uses the `XremoveAnnotation` plugin from [HiSrc HyperJAXB Annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) to ***remove*** the annotations, followed by [`ann.xml`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/main/resources/org/example/po/) resource files together with the [HiSrc BasicJAXB Annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb-annox#readme) library to rebind a JAXB context, in memory.

> Note: The [HiSrc HyperJAXB Annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) project is an updated fork of [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin#readme). The demo [schema](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/main/resources/PurchaseOrder.xsd) and [binding](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/main/resources/PurchaseOrder.xjb) used here is a substitute for the OP's older schema reference. *Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the forked HiSrc projects.

The selective removal of **JAXB** annotations is configured in the [XJB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/main/resources/PurchaseOrder.xjb) file, here's a snippet:

**PurchaseOrder.xjb**

```
...
<!-- Items -->
<jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='Items']">
    <annox:removeAnnotation target="class" class="jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType"/>
    <annox:removeAnnotation target="class" class="jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
...
```

Next, the [Main](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/main/java/org/example/po/Main.java) and [PurchaseOrderTest](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/test/java/org/example/po/PurchaseOrderTest.java) classes each create a `JAXBContext` with an `AnnoxAnnotationReader` to read [`ann.xml`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox/blob/master/assembly/samples/resourced/src/main/resources/org/example/po/) resource files and ***rebind*** the annotations in memory. Thus, the generated **JAXB** classes become *Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs)* while the context is provided in memory.

**JAXBContext plus AnnoxAnnotationReader**

```
RuntimeAnnotationReader annotationReader = new AnnoxAnnotationReader();
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, annotationReader);
Class<?>[] classes = { ObjectFactory.class };
setJaxbContext(JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, properties));
```

Answer (score 0):

We have updated the jaxb-annotate-plugin in [jaxb-tools](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) (former location of `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin`, merged with jaxb2-basics, jaxb-annotate-plugin and other related repository), since your problem is related to an issue we filled in there : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/issues/340

The next release will include a new `RemoveXmlAnnotation` Plugin, activable via `-XremoveXmlAnnotation` option (and an extra `XremoveXmlAnnotation:removeObjectFactory` option to remove ObjectFactory class).

The [PR](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/pull/456) has been created and is actually under review. If needed, will be able to backport it to v2 version of the plugin.

Feel free to look at our [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) since many artifacts where relocated.

**EDIT 06/02/2024** : 4.0.2 released, enjoy !

Comment: Thanks for the help and possible solution. Unfortunately I cannot test it anymore, since I am working in another project for another company. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. As I said, it was an existing issue in jaxb-tools repository, linked to your need. It'll be part of the 4.0.1 release and should be backported in 2.0.10 (jaxb 2.3 based version).